# Style Radio Buttons inside Edit Page (Custom Fields)

Tags: customization, wp-admin, css, advanced-custom-fields, admin-css

I created styles for custom field, that is a radio button.

The style affects every `.inside ul.acf-radio-list.radio.horizontal li label` but I want the style to work only on the Edit Post functionality.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add your styles to **/your-theme/admin-edit-post.css**

```
.inside ul.acf-radio-list.radio.horizontal li label {
 /* styles... */
}
```

Then enqueue the styles by adding this to your theme's `functions.php`:

```
function wpse250000_admin_styles( $hook ) {
    // Bail if we're not on the post.php admin page
    if ( 'post.php' !== $hook ) {
        return;
    }

    // Ensure we're looking at a post. Add other post types to array if desired.
    $post_type = get_post_type();
    if ( ! $post_type || ! in_array( $post_type, [ 'post' ] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_style( 'admin-edit-post-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-edit-post.css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse250000_admin_styles' );
```